# What is meant by keeps breaking out the control structure and then back in again?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

My teacher emailed me about my homework which was to write a code about renting a car:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim age, credit As Integer
    Dim name As String

    Console.WriteLine("This programme determines whether you can rent a car.")
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name...")
    name = Console.ReadLine

    Console.WriteLine(name & " how old are you?")
    age = Console.ReadLine

    Console.WriteLine("How much does your credit card currently hold? (£)")
    credit = Console.ReadLine

    If age < 18 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, " & name & " you are not old enough to rent a car, please use the bicycle hire company!")
    End If

    If age >= 18 And credit >= 5000 Then
        Console.WriteLine(name & " you are able to rent a car!")
    End If

    If age >= 18 And credit < 5000 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, " & name & " You are currently not able to rent a car.")
    End If

End Sub
```

This is the way I asked you not to do it as though it works it keeps breaking out the control structure and then back in again. Can you use Else Ifs please.

What does he mean by "it keeps breaking out the control structure and then back in again."

Is this the correct code using ElseIf:

```
  Sub Main()
    Dim age, credit As Integer
    Dim name As String

    Console.WriteLine("This programme determines whether you can rent a car.")
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name...")
    name = Console.ReadLine

    Console.WriteLine(name & " how old are you?")
    age = Console.ReadLine

    Console.WriteLine("How much does your credit card currently hold? (£)")
    credit = Console.ReadLine()
    If age >= 18 And credit >= 5000 Then
        Console.WriteLine(name & " you are able to rent a car!")
    ElseIf age >= 18 And credit < 5000 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, " & name & " you are currently not able to rent a car.")
    ElseIf age < 18 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, " & name & " you are not old enough to rent a car, please use the bicycle hire company!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please dont add tags to titles.  I *think* he means mainly to use `ElseIf` as one structure as you did in the rewrite.  As an `If/ElseIF` it is one block versus 3; rather than block, he is calling it a structure.  ('Breaking out' is an odd way to put it though - it is not like you used `GOTO`).

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry about that, Stacknoob here (also VB noob). Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

No.  While I don't know what your teacher's is trying to teach you (you should really ask him, he's the professional educator and getting paid to do that job), I'm sure he meant this:

```
If age < 18 Then
    Console.WriteLine("...")
ElseIf credit < 5000 Then
    Console.WriteLine("...")
Else 
    Console.WriteLine(name & " you are able to rent a car!")
End If
```

Note how this code is *much* simpler to maintain.  Changing the age or credit limit requires editing only a single statement.  This drastically reduces the odds for mistakes, easier to read as well.

Comment: To expand on Hans' answer, in the OP's code, *all* the tests are tried, and it's only because of the specific conditions that only one will pass. Conversely, in the venerable Hans' code, the *structure* guarantees that only one test will be tried. This is what makes it more maintainable - it would be easy to introduce a bug into the original code by amending just one of the tests without looking closely at the others. . .